# Submit action does not take me to the Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have got a JSP page, It has button AddTile with value = submit, 
When this button is pressed I want to take the control to servlet Here is the Form Section of the JSP Page

```
<form action="webservlets/DatabaseConnector" id="tileform" name="tileform" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="Get">
        <fieldset>
            <div id="tiletype">
                <input type="radio" name="tile" id= "initial" value="initial" checked>
                <label for="initial">Initial tile</label>
            </div>
            <div id="tilefield">
                <label for="initlength" class="title">Length</label>
                <input type="text" id="initlength" name="initlength" size="8" title="Enter length of tile in metres" autofocus>
            </div>
            <div id="tilefield">
                <label for="initangle" class="title">Direction</label>
                <input type="text" id="initangle" name="initangle" size="8" title="Enter initial direction in degrees">
            </div>
            <div id="tilefield">
                <label for="init_x" class="title">x-coordinate</label>
                <input type="text" id="init_x" name="init_x" size="8" title="Enter starting position x-axis">
            </div>
            <div id="tilefield">
                <label for="init_y" class="title">y-coordinate</label>
                <input type="text" id="init_y" name="init_y" size="8" title="Enter starting position y-axis">
            </div>
        </fieldset>
            <p>
        <fieldset>
            <div id="tiletype">
                <input type="radio" name="tile" id="longitudinal" value="longitudinal" disabled>
                <label for="longitudinal">Longitudinal tile</label>
            </div>
            <div id="tilefield">
                <label for="longlength" class="title">Length</label>
                <input type="text" id="longlength" name="longlength" size="8" disabled>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
            <p>
        <fieldset>
            <div id="tiletype">
                <input type="radio" name="tile" id="curved" value="curved" disabled>
                <label for="curved">Curved tile</label>
            </div>
            <div id="tilefield">
                <label for="curveradius" class="title">Radius</label>
                <input type="text" id="curveradius" name="curveradius" size="8" disabled>
            </div>
            <div id="tilefield">
                <label for="curveangle" class="title">Angle</label>
                <input type="text" id="curveangle" name="curveangle" value="" size="8" disabled>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
            <p>
            <button type="reset" id="buttons" onclick="reset()">Clear </button>
            <button type="submit" id="buttons" name = "initial" value="initial">AddTile</button>
        </form>
```

My Servlet is located src > webservlets(package name)> DatabaseConnector

here is the code of my servlet

```
@WebServlet("/DatabaseConnector")
public class DatabaseConnector extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public DatabaseConnector() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Servlet now connected"+request.getParameter("name"));
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the JavaScript behind validateForm()

Comment: Your web servlet define url=`"/DatabaseConnector"`. Your javascript form define action=`"webservlets/DatabaseConnector"`. Is that intentional ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using GET method, you can more easily test your app. According to your web.xml, servlet url may change. According to your web.xml and where your jsp files located jsp submit url may change.

1. [Run your servlet](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseWTP/article.html) in the Server. See which url your browser shows.
2. Submit your from browser. See which url your browser shows.

Urls from 1 and 2 should be same.

Comment: Sorry I do not follow your statement "According to your web.xml and where your jsp files located jsp submit url may change. "

Comment: In your web.xml you may decide remap your servlet to XYZ/DBC